# Visual Basic increment letter number combo

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a need to increment when outputting data from the VB program I am writing into excel (this is a stand alone program not VBA).

What I want is to have the cell increment down 34 cells and start again.

```
AR0 = 34
AR1 = "A" + 36 + AR0
```

So the answer that I am trying to get is that AR1 would now equal A70.
How can I achieve this?

full block of code

```
If Tnumber = 2 Then
        TextboxNP = TSPlus.TextBox218.Text
        TextboxNTC = TSPlus.TextBox189.Text
        TextboxNWD = TSPlus.TextBox80.Text
        Range1 = AR1 + AR0
        Range2 = AR2 + AR0
        Range3 = AR3 + AR0
        Range4 = AR4 + AR0   '
        Range5 = AR5 + AR0
        Range6 = AR6 + AR0
        Range7 = AR7 + AR0
        Range8 = AR8 + AR0
        Range9 = AR9 + AR0
        Range10 = AR10 + AR0
        Range11 = AR11 + AR0
        Range12 = AR12 + AR0
        Range13 = AR13 + AR0
        Range14 = AR14 + AR0
        Range15 = AR15 + AR0
        Range16 = AR16 + AR0
        Range17 = AR17 + AR0
        Range18 = AR18 + AR0
        Range19 = AR19 + AR0
        Range20 = AR20 + AR0
        Range21 = AR21 + AR0
        Range22 = AR22 + AR0
        Range23 = AR23 + AR0
        Range24 = AR24 + AR0
        Range25 = AR25 + AR0
        Range26 = AR26 + AR0
        Range27 = AR27 + AR0
        Range28 = AR28 + AR0
        Range29 = AR29 + AR0
        Range30 = AR30 + AR0
        Range31 = AR31 + AR0
        Range32 = AR32 + AR0
        Range33 = AR33 + AR0
        Range34 = AR34 + AR0
        Range35 = AR35 + AR0

    End If
```

This is the next block from the snippet my hope was the by the time Tnumber = 2 that AR1 will = "A36"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Are you looking to do this via formulas or a macro?

Comment: In a formula. the code listed is with in an IF statement.

Comment: And will you always be incrementing by 36?  And does the "A" ever need to be a different letter?

Comment: Increment will be by 34. and the "A" will change per variable that will create the form.